# Multimatch query with Fuzzy NEST - ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I wrote the following query to check multiple fields from a value and it's work:

```
    var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(a => a
        .Fields(f => f
        .Field(p => p.Attachment.Content)
        .Field(p => p.FileName))
        .Query(queryValue))));
```

I would achieve the same result (search the queryValue in fields Attachment.Content and FileName) but with the Fuzzy mechanism (for example, if queryValue is "esting" I would get back also a result with filename "testing").

Thanks a lot! C# netCore 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Search using characters in Elasticsearch.

You can use the following query for your results: (Note: must read the comments)

```
//finds all strings starting with queryValue
//string queryValue = queryValue + "*";

//finds all strings containing queryValue
string queryValue = "*" + queryValue + "*";

//finds all strings ending with queryValue
//string queryValue = "*" + queryValue;
        
var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                .QueryString(qs => qs
                .Query(queryValue)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(Attachment.Content)//first field
                    .Field(FileName)//second field
                ))));
```